# .map() function does not render out message in react.js

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to render a

```
<Message msg={message} />
```

component in react.js using .map() but if I do not pass the message variable in {} brackets it errors but when I do pass the message variable in the {} brackets, it does not display the message.

for example:

```
<div className="messages">
       {/* this is where the error happens if I dont put the message variable in {} */}
       {messages.map(({ message }) => (
          <Message msg={message} />
       ))}
    </div>
```

the error it returns is:

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, message}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

Here is the whole file:

```
import db from "../firebase";
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./Chat.css";
import Message from "./Message";

const Chat = () => {
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    //run once when the app components loads
    db.collection("messages")
      .orderBy("timestamp", "desc")
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        setMessages(
          snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ([{ id: doc.id, message: doc.data() }]))
        );
      });
  }, []);

  const sendMessage = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    db.collection("messages").add({
      message: input,
      timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    })

    setMessages([...messages, {message: input}]);
    setInput("");
  };

  return (
    <div className="chat-card overflow-scroll shadow-md mx-auto p-5 w-10/12 h-10/12">
      <h1 className="text-white text-center font-bold text-lg">
        Community Chat
      </h1>

      <div className="my-5 mx-auto">
        <form onSubmit={sendMessage}>
          <input
            value={input}
            onChange={(event) => setInput(event.target.value)}
            className="w-full py-2 rounded"
            type="text"
          />
          <button className="w-full text-white font-bold my-2 rounded bg-red-500 py-2">
            SEND
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>

      <div className="messages">
            {messages.map(( message ) => (
                <Message msg={message} />
            ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Chat;
```

Comment: Could you give an example of what data is stored within the "messages" array?

Comment: It looks like `messages` is an object instead of an array, which prompts the `found: object with keys {id, message}`. As @bryyytl mentioned, it'd be great if you could provide an example of what `messages` look like.

Comment: The input value (whatever the user types in the message bar). But I am using firebases firestore to make it realtime.

Comment: messages is just "const [messages, setMessages] = useState([])

Comment: messages is an array of objects. Each of those objects has a `id` and `message` property. So I think you want `messages.map(message => <Message msg={message.message} />`.

Comment: Sorry for such a late reply. I ended up scrapping the project and rebuilding it from scratch. Everything is pretty much the same and I got it working but it is outputting a number not the message being sent :(

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the `Message` component is expecting a string in the `msg` prop. This is most likely what is causing the error since the array of messages actually is an array of objects. In the `sendMessage` method you set the message state like this:

```
setMessages([...messages, {message: input}]);
```

Wrapping the message in `{}` appends it as an object to the array instead, which is why you need to restructure it, like `(({ message }) => ...)` in the render method.

One solution is to change the way you set the Messages state like so:

```
setMessages([...messages, input]);
```

You could also just keep the destructuring as you're already doing. This is actually a rather fine and simple solution and there is no need to fix it if it works. Destructuring is a very common approach in `.map` methods if you're dealing with objects.

To prevent issues like this in the future or to have clearer error messages, I'd suggest using [PropTypes](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types) for validating the props you're expecting to receive. If used, it would have told you that the `msg` prop in the `Message` component requires a string and not an object.